# Can social studio pull in Reddit data?

Tags: integration, social-studio

I am currently researching the option of pulling reddit data into salesforce social studio. But found very little information online.

https://www.salesforce.com/products/marketing-cloud/best-practices/social-media-monitoring/ (in this article they are referring to Reddit as a social channel but it is unclear to me whether that is visible in social studio
I have also tried adding it as a source group (both URL and RSS feed) but didnt give any results
Any other suggestions? or anyone who has said it up before.

Thanks a lot. Regards, Marloes

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not.  Per their [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ss_connect_a_new_social_account.htm&type=5):

> With Social Studio, you can add Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, YouTube,
> Pinterest, Google My Business, Sina Weibo, Instagram, and Instagram
> Business social accounts.